# Kafka service start fail

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to install kafka on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I followed instruction of below link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04

As I end up create /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
and try to start service with 'sudo systemctl start kafka'

It doesn't print any message, I could know that starting service is failed by checking output of

**sudo journalctl -u**

It says

**sudo journalctl -u kafka**

```
<pre><code>
kafka.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL
kafka.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
kafka.service: Unit entered failed state.
kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
</code></pre>
```

**cat kafka.log**

```
<pre><code>
java
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,241] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,449] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,449] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,459] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,462] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,462] INFO Client environment:host.name=4whomtbts (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,462] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_242 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,462] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Private Build (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-08 00:01:08,462] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)

... skipped ...

[2020-02-08 00:01:15,208] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-08 00:01:15,211]<b> ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:268)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:264)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:97)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1693)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.kafka$server$KafkaServer$$createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:348)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:372)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) </b>
[2020-02-08 00:01:15,214] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-08 00:01:15,218] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-08 00:01:15,218] <b>ERROR Exiting Kafka. </b>(kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2020-02-08 00:01:15,220] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)


</code></pre>
```

### **+more Zookeeper information**

/var/log/zookeeper contains no file.

**zookeeper.service**

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh 
/home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**service --status-all**

```
    ... skipped ... 
    [ - ]  umountnfs.sh
    [ - ]  umountroot
    [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
    [ + ]  urandom
    [ - ]  uuidd
    [ + ]  whoopsie
    [ - ]  x11-common
    [ + ]  zookeeper
```

**sudo journalctl -u zookeeper**

```
systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
```

I couldn't find out any clue to solve this problem by googling :(

My environment information is..

Machine : LG gram 2019 15.4

OS : Ubuntu 16.04, kernel version 5

java : openJDK 1.8.0

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Post also Zookeeper's logs.

Comment: @ErgiNushi I'vs appended more information about zookeeper. howerver, Zookeeper log directory contains no log file.

Comment: You can change ExecStart in zookeeper service to send zookeper logs to zookeeper.log like this:

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties > /home/kafka/zookeeper.log 2>&1'
It seems it's a problem about zookeper. You need zookeper logs to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Why not follow official Apache site? Or use Ansible / Puppet / Chef?

Comment: Hello, Did you solve this? :/

Answer (score -1):

Your zookeeper server may be gone to idle state. You can just to go to the terminal of zookeeper and hit enter. After that you can try again.